# Erase any string that doesn't match a pattern using replaceall()

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace ALL characters that don't follow a pattern with `""`.

I have strings like:

```
MCC-QX-1081
TEF-CO-QX-4949
SPARE-QX-4500
```

So far the closest I am using the following regex.

```
String regex = "[^QX,-,\\d]";
```

Using the `replaceAll` String method I get `QX1081` and the expected result is `QX-1081`

Comment: You are using a negated character class with a range from a comma to a comma. You have to either escape the hyphen or put it at the start or at the end like `[^QX,\d-]`. But that will result in `-QX-1081` What do you want to match or remove exactly?

Comment: I want to match just QX-#### and erase anything else

Comment: Can something follow after QX-####, and will there always be a QX-#### part?

Comment: Do you have to remove the rest or could you also match the end like `\bQX-\d+$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WA2N9/1/)

Comment: @DavidSalasBoscan There are multiple answers given to assist you. If there is an answer that solves your problem consider to [mark an answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and feel free to [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) the answers you consider to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches single characters, not patterns.

You want something like

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("^.*?(QX-\\d+)?$", "$1");
```

which works as long as nothing follows the `QX-digits` part in your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Put the dash at the end of the regex: [^QX,\d-]
Next you just have to substring to filter out the first dash.
Don't know exactly what you expect for all strings but if you want to match a dash in a character class then it must be set as last character.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a character class where you have to either escape the hyphen or put it at the start or at the end like `[^QX,\d-]` or else you are matching a range from a comma to a comma. But changing that  will give you `-QX-1081` which is not the desired result.

You could match your pattern and then replace with the first capturing group `$1`:

```
^(?:[A-Z]+-)+(QX-\d+)$
```

In Java you have to double escape matching a digit `\\d`

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:[A-Z]+-)+` Repeat 1+ times one or more uppercase charactacters followed by a hyphen
- `(QX-\d+)` Capture in a group `QX-` followed by 1+ digits
- `$` End of the string

For example:

```
String result = "MCC-QX-1081".replaceAll("^(?:[A-Z]+-)+(QX-\\d+)$", "$1");
System.out.println(result); // QX-1081
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2TGCrf/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tbEYV9)

Note that if you are doing just 1 replacement, you could also use `replaceFirst`